# Ubuntu 16.04 software sync

Tags: 16.04, software-center, ubuntu-one, sync

In Ubuntu 15.04 LTS , Ubuntu Software Center had an option "Sync between computers.." to sync list of packages on my desktop with Ubuntu One account.
but in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Ubuntu Software lacks this option .
How do I access this option?

Comment: the service is obsolete