# Login panel missing in Ubuntu software center

Tags: login, software-center, ubuntu-one

I was trying to sync software between my computers. However, on my fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I am unable to locate the login panel in Ubuntu Software Center (where I can supposedly login with my Ubuntu One account). As shown, I am missing the login panel on the left. Please advise.

[image]

EDIT: In contrast, on my other machine running Ubuntu Kylin 16.04 LTS the panel is functional and I can login to my Ubuntu One account. 
[image]

Comment: http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/819906/ubuntu-16-04-software-sync

Comment: Right under the Launcher icon for the Software Center in your screenshot is a bright blue icon for reporting the error you got. If you can reproduce the error, please add that information to your question.

Comment: The error icon was for something else, I can reproduce the situation without raising an error.